# Touch up outside location from UI Button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to write a method that receives the coordinates of a ending touch event when a user touches a button and then drags off off the button. Is the touch coordinate information available if the button is passed into the method as the sender? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch coordinates information is not available form the sender. But your action's selector can take the form

```
-(IBAction)dragOutside:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

and the `event` does contain the coordinates and other things.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the coordinate information in the sender function of `UIButton`. you could use to detect touch events by implementing  the `UIResponder` functions.

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
- touchesEnded:withEvent:
```

Have a look SO post

[How do you recognize drag gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345154/how-do-you-recognize-drag-gestures)